# Correct Syntax for SQL query inside C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am currently using a asp.net webform to pull data from a database in mssql. I have three tables (tOptions, tModel, tOptions_Model) and the datafields are (OptionsID, Options, ModelID, Model). What the form does, is when you select one of the models from the dropdownlist, it will send a sql query to grab all of the options that correspond to that model. The error i am running into, is when you select one of the models from the dropdownlist, this is the error received:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '3' (the 3 represents the model selected inside the dropdownlist, so it would be the third item in the ddl). My question is, is this the correct way to grab all the options based on the model selected?

```
    public partial class ModelsAndOptions : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn;
    private static SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs comm;
    private static SqlDataReader reader;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            OpenConnection();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int optionsID;
        string options;
        ListItem optionsItem;
        // clear the listbox just in case something is already inside it.
        lbxOptions.Items.Clear();

        string result = ("SELECT Options, OptionsID FROM tOptions WHERE ID = '('" + ddlModel.SelectedValue + "')'");


        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(result, conn);

        try
        {
            reader.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
         //use reader obj to execute query
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        // iterate through dataset by each line
      while (reader.Read())
        {
            // stores primary key of options
            optionsID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            // stores name
            options = reader.GetString(1);
            // creates a list item with text of both the primary key and the name
            optionsItem = new ListItem(options, optionsID.ToString());
            // add items to the listbox
            lbxOptions.Items.Add(optionsItem);
        }
    }

    private void OpenConnection()
    {
       System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings strConn;

       strConn = ReadConnectionString();

          conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConn.ConnectionString);



       try
       {
           conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
   private System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings ReadConnectionString()
   {
        //string to store the path 
        String strPath;
        strPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Web.config";

         //object that points to web.config file
        System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(strPath);

        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString = null;

        // if the connection string is working, then set the object to equal the connection string located inside the web.config file
       if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["kroegedlConnectionString"];
        }

        // return the connection string setting obj
        return connString;
    }

    protected void btnAddOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxChosenOptions.Items.Add(lbxOptions.SelectedItem);
        lbxOptions.Items.Remove(lbxOptions.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: SQL Injection alert!!! Your code is wide open to sql injection attack. You need to use parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Your code has a number of other issues here too. You are not properly disposing of connection and command objects which will kill your connection pool. You also have what I call a try/squelch, which is a try catch but the catch doesn't do anything. This is an anti-pattern that is worse than not catching the error in the first place.

Comment: For the issue at hand you need to look into databinding. You don't need to loop through resultsets like this and populate dropdown boxes manually.

Comment: Best way for you to troubleshoot the query would've been to output the `result` string and paste it into Sql Server Management Studio if seeing the actual query string is not enough. (You're querying for `WHERE ID = '('3')'`, which is invalid syntax; it's an constant integer 3 mushed between two single character strings that happen to hold parenthesis).

Answer (score 2):

Too many sins commited

```
 // Extract method: do not cram everything into single IndexChanged  
 private void CoreAddOptions() {
   // Do not open a global connection
   // Wrap IDisposable into using 
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) { 
     conn.Open(); 

     // Make Sql Readable
     // Make Sql paramterized  
     string sql = 
       @"select Options,
                OptionsID
           from tOptions
          where Id = @prm_Id"; 

     // Wrap IDisposable into using
     using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
       // Do not hardcode SQL but use parameters
       comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Id", ddlModel.SelectedValue);

       // Wrap IDisposable into using
       using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader()) {
         while (reader.Read()) {
           // Use Convert instead of Get + ToString
           var optionsItem = new ListItem(
             Convert.ToString(reader[0]),
             Convert.ToString(reader[1]));

           lbxOptions.Items.Add(optionsItem); 
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Then

```
 protected void ddlModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   CoreAddOptions();    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure and pass validated parameters to it. 
This mitigates against SQL injection and allows you to test your code more easily.

Wrap all resources in a using statement to ensure they are disposed of.